# I cannot get Ethereum Wallet to run on windows64

Tags: ethereum

I trying out Ethereum for the first time. I was able to get Ethereum wallet downloaded and installed on my Windows 10 system. Now when I try to launch .exe file I get "Could connect to node? See the logs for". I have attached a screenshot.

Any ideas of how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks!

[image: Mist error message]

[image]

Comment: this question might be off topic here. if you feel your questions do not recieve enough attention on stackoverflow, you can also try asking ethereum-specific questions on the new [ethereum stack exchange beta site](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The mistake I was making, The path that I pointed to the geth.exe in commandline was from a download outside of the Ethereum dir. When I ran geth from ethereum\Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-6-2\Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-6-2\resources\node\geth as opposed to desktop/geth that I downloaded separately then Ethereum began to run as expected.

I hope this helps someone else in need!

[image]